# How do I make a 1x1x2 piston door that opens when I step on a plate and not the other way around?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In *Minecraft* I need to make a piston door that opens when a plate is stepped on, it is normally the other way around. Does anyone know how? A video would be helpful but not required.

Comment: Insert a not gate (ie. input into a single redstone torch) between the plate and the door?

Answer (score 9):

Simply put in a NOT Gate. A not gate is a redstone current running into a block which has a redstone torch attached to it (as shown in the first screenshot).

[image: Wiring]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example that uses a NOT gate.

[image: Door]

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the door working (but inverted) just connect the pressure plate to the pistons using a NOT gate (a torch on a block) to invert the signal and therefore the door.

Answer (score 0):

Put [a NOT gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits#NOT_gate_.28.C2.AC.29) on your line from the pressure plate to the pistons.

Answer (score 0):

Put a "not gate" from the Pistons to the pressure plates (if you're using them). A not gate is where you make a redstone trail up to a redstone torch on a 1x1 wall. Then on the other side of the block, you make another redstone trail to directly underneath the pressure plate/whatever else you're using and (optional) one more trail on the right side of the block (redstone torch view) to directly underneath your other pressure plate.